# Accuracy in Classfication Report lower than best estimator from GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I performed a grid search on an MLPClassifier.

Why the accuracy in classification report (0.76) is not identical to the highest split test score (in this case 0.80) in the dataframe?

Output:
[image]

Code:

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=200, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=1)
param_grid = {'learning_rate_init': [1e-5,1e-4], 'hidden_layer_sizes': [(50,),(50,50)],'max_iter':[100], 'activation':['logistic','relu']} 

print("Finding optimal Hyper-parameters within the specified grid...")
grid = GridSearchCV(MLPClassifier(),param_grid,verbose=0, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
a = grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
grid_predictions = a.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)

cm = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, grid_predictions)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=grid.classes_)
disp.plot(cmap='Blues')
plt.show()

print(sklearn.metrics.classification_report(y_test,grid_predictions, digits=6))
print("BEST PARAMETERS FOUND:",format(grid.best_params_))
print("BEST - Mean Accuracy:",format(round(grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score'][grid.best_index_],6)))
print("BEST - Standard Deviation Accuracy:",format(round(grid.cv_results_['std_test_score'][grid.best_index_],3)))
print("BEST - Mean Time:{}s".format(round(grid.cv_results_['mean_fit_time'][grid.best_index_],3)))
print("BEST - Standard Deviation Time:{}s".format(round(grid.cv_results_['std_fit_time'][grid.best_index_],3)))

pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)
```

Comment: What is supposed to be reported is the **mean** score, not the score in any single split (like `split0` which you have highlighted here); so there *is* a question here (namely why the confusion matrix shows an accuracy of 0.76, and not the mean one of 0.646667), but not the one you are asking...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your report you are using your test set (X_test and y_test), these data are not seen at all in the grid search (as expected) you are then running one classification task on 2 different dataset, there is absolutely no guarantee that score are exactly same. In that case, it is lower on test set, it could be the opposite although since you are taking the highest result on all split it is likely to be higher that on a new random dataset like your test set.
You should probably compare the result in report with mean_test_score instead with is actually lower in your case.